# XmlID/XmlIDREF and inheritance in latest JAXB version (Java 7)

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb, java-7

I am using @XmlID and @XmlIDREF tags to reference one object from another. It was working fine in Java 6 even with inherited classes. The example code I've created looks like this.
Base class used tags:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class Module {
    Module() {}

    @XmlIDREF
    private Module other;

    @XmlID
    private String id;

    public Module(String id, Module other) {
        this.id = id;
        this.other = other;
    }
}
```

Inherited class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TheModule extends Module {
    TheModule() {}

    private String feature;

    public TheModule(String id, Module other, String feature) {
        super(id, other);
        this.feature = feature;
    }
}
```

Container for these classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Script {
    Script() {}
    public Script(Collection<Module> modules) {
        this.modules = modules;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElementRef
    Collection<Module> modules = new ArrayList<Module>();
}
```

When running this example code:

```
public class JaxbTest {

    private Script createScript() {
        Module m1 = new Module("Module1", null);
        Module m2 = new TheModule("Module2", m1, "featured  module");
        Module m3 = new Module("Module3", m2);
        return new Script(Arrays.asList(m1, m2, m3));
    }

    private String marshal(Script script) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Module.class, Script.class, TheModule.class);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        context.createMarshaller().marshal(script, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }

    private void runTest() throws Exception {
        Script script = createScript();

        System.out.println(marshal(script));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        new JaxbTest().runTest();
    }
}
```

I receive XML, in Java 6:

```
<script>
  <modules>
    <module>
      <id>Module1</id>
    </module>
    <theModule>
      <other>Module1</other>
      <id>Module2</id>
      <feature>featured module</feature>
    </theModule>
    <module>
      <other>Module2</other>
      <id>Module3</id>
    </module>
  </modules>
</script>
```

Note that reference to the m2 (TheModule instance) is serialized as expected.
But when the same code is running under Java 7 (Jaxb 2.2.4-1) I receive:

```
<script>
  <modules>
    <module>
      <id>Module1</id>
    </module>
    <theModule>
      <other>Module1</other>
      <id>Module2</id>
      <feature>featured module</feature>
    </theModule>
    <module>
      <other xsi:type="theModule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <other>Module1</other>
        <id>Module2</id>
        <feature>featured module</feature>
      </other>
      <id>Module3</id>
    </module>
  </modules>
</script>
```

So you can see that on latest JAXB @XmlIDREF for inherited module is not working!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is *wrong*. Instead of relying on it read the documentation for [`JAXBContext.newInstance(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class...%29), see [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615180/433835) and the comments below.

---

I think you confuse JAXB with the following line.

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Module.class, Script.class, TheModule.class);
```

You tell it that you want to serialize the XML types `Script`, `Module` and `TheModule`. JAXB will treat objects of this latter type in a *special* way, because you've already supplied its base class: it adds a discriminating attribute to it. This way these two types can be differentiated in the serialized XML.

Try supplying only `Script` and `Module`, the base class for *all* modules.

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Module.class, Script.class);
```

In fact, you can leave out `Module` entirely. JAXB will infer types in the `Script` object you try to serialize from the context.

This behaviour by the way isn't *exactly* related to Java 6. It's related to the JAXB implementation in use (okay-okay, almost the same thing, I know). In my projects I use JAXB 2.2.4-1, which reproduces the issue at hand in Java 6 and 7 too.

Oh, and one more thing: instead of creating a `StringWriter` and marshalling objects into that, then sending its contents to `System.out` you can use the following to send formatted XML to `stdout`.

```
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.marshal(script, System.out);
```

Maybe this can ease (a tiny little bit) further testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some doubts. Javadoc for JAXBContext.newInstance(Class...) states that caller must list top-level classes. "new context will recognize all the classes specified, but it will also recognize any classes that are directly/indirectly referenced **statically** (sic!) from the specified classes. Subclasses of referenced classes nor @XmlTransient referenced classes are not registered with JAXBContext.". 

If we apply this statement to Konstantin's example, descendant class TheModule will not be auto-discovered.
\

Comment: @AndyMalakov It seems you're right. I don't remember exactly if I've read the documentation for `newInstance` back then when I answered the question, but I remember that I've tried some code and what I've written seemed to check out. As the OP didn't respond to my answer in any way I've just forgotten about this entirely. Actually I can see that I've misinterpreted the actual question/problem so my answer is totally off. I'll update my answer to reflect this. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug in JAXB. I had the same problem and resolved it by not using XmlIDRef, but rather using postDeserialize with a custom ID.

Here is a bug report:

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-870

I couldn't use Kohányi Róbert's suggestion. Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck with Java7 in 2017, then there is an easy way to circumvent this. The problem is that when serialiazing with a XmlREFId, Jaxb can't cope with sub-classes. A solution is to use an adapter and return an new instance of the base class with the same id as the one being serialized (only the id will be used, so we don't need to bother with the other fields):

```
public class ModuleXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Module, Module> {
    @Override
    public Module unmarshal(Module v) {
        // there is no problem with deserializing - return as is
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Module marshal(Module v) {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // here is the trick:
        return new Module(v.getId(), null);
    }
}
```

Then, just use that adapter wherever needed:

```
public class Module {
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ModuleXmlAdapter.class)
    private Module other;

    //...
}
```